# How to fix this "missing EOF at 'finally'" error?

Tags: antlr4, antlr3

Converting Antlr 3 grammar to Antlr 4. This is the parser for MySQL which was written in v3 and I am trying to convert to v4. The error is on the line at the bottom with the 'finally'. The error says"
**"missing EOF at 'finally'"**

```
// Comment from server yacc grammar:
//   Keywords that we allow for labels in SPs. Anything that's the beginning of a statement
//   or characteristics must be in keyword above, otherwise we get (harmful) shift/reduce conflicts.
// Additionally:
//   The keywords are only roughly sorted to stay with the same order as in sql_yacc.yy (for simpler diff'ing).
keyword_sp:
    ACTION_SYMBOL
    | ADDDATE_SYMBOL
    | AFTER_SYMBOL
    | AGAINST_SYMBOL
    | AGGREGATE_SYMBOL
    | ALGORITHM_SYMBOL
    | ANALYZE_SYMBOL
    | ANY_SYMBOL
    | AT_SYMBOL
    | AUTHORS_SYMBOL
    | AUTO_INCREMENT_SYMBOL
    | AUTOEXTEND_SIZE_SYMBOL
    | AVG_ROW_LENGTH_SYMBOL
    | AVG_SYMBOL
    | BINLOG_SYMBOL
    | BIT_SYMBOL
    | BLOCK_SYMBOL
    | BOOL_SYMBOL
    | BOOLEAN_SYMBOL
    | BTREE_SYMBOL
    | CASCADED_SYMBOL
    | CATALOG_NAME_SYMBOL
    | CHAIN_SYMBOL
    | CHANGED_SYMBOL
    | CHANNEL_SYMBOL // Conditionally set in the lexer.
    | CIPHER_SYMBOL
    | CLIENT_SYMBOL
    | CLASS_ORIGIN_SYMBOL
    | COALESCE_SYMBOL
    | CODE_SYMBOL
    | COLLATION_SYMBOL
    | COLUMN_NAME_SYMBOL
    | COLUMN_FORMAT_SYMBOL
    | COLUMNS_SYMBOL
    | COMMITTED_SYMBOL
    | COMPACT_SYMBOL
    | COMPLETION_SYMBOL
    | COMPRESSED_SYMBOL
    | COMPRESSION_SYMBOL // Conditionally set in the lexer.
    | CONCURRENT_SYMBOL
    | CONNECTION_SYMBOL
    | CONSISTENT_SYMBOL
    | CONSTRAINT_CATALOG_SYMBOL
    | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA_SYMBOL
    | CONSTRAINT_NAME_SYMBOL
    | CONTEXT_SYMBOL
    | CONTRIBUTORS_SYMBOL
    | CPU_SYMBOL
    | CUBE_SYMBOL
    | CURRENT_SYMBOL
    | CURSOR_NAME_SYMBOL
    | DATA_SYMBOL
    | DATAFILE_SYMBOL
    | DATETIME_SYMBOL
    | DATE_SYMBOL
    | DAY_SYMBOL
    | DEFAULT_AUTH_SYMBOL
    | DEFINER_SYMBOL
    | DELAY_KEY_WRITE_SYMBOL
    | DES_KEY_FILE_SYMBOL
    | DIAGNOSTICS_SYMBOL
    | DIRECTORY_SYMBOL
    | DISABLE_SYMBOL
    | DISCARD_SYMBOL
    | DISK_SYMBOL
    | DUMPFILE_SYMBOL
    | DUPLICATE_SYMBOL
    | DYNAMIC_SYMBOL
    | ENDS_SYMBOL
    | ENUM_SYMBOL
    | ENGINE_SYMBOL
    | ENGINES_SYMBOL
    | ERROR_SYMBOL
    | ERRORS_SYMBOL
    | ESCAPE_SYMBOL
    | EVENT_SYMBOL
    | EVENTS_SYMBOL
    | EVERY_SYMBOL
    | EXPANSION_SYMBOL
    | EXPORT_SYMBOL
    | EXTENDED_SYMBOL
    | EXTENT_SIZE_SYMBOL
    | FAULTS_SYMBOL
    | FAST_SYMBOL
    | FOUND_SYMBOL
    | ENABLE_SYMBOL
    | FULL_SYMBOL
    | FILE_SYMBOL
    | FILE_BLOCK_SIZE_SYMBOL // Conditionally set in the lexer.
    | FILTER_SYMBOL
    | FIRST_SYMBOL
    | FIXED_SYMBOL
    | GENERAL_SYMBOL
    | GEOMETRY_SYMBOL
    | GEOMETRYCOLLECTION_SYMBOL
    | GET_FORMAT_SYMBOL
    | GRANTS_SYMBOL
    | GLOBAL_SYMBOL
    | HASH_SYMBOL
    | HOSTS_SYMBOL
    | HOUR_SYMBOL
    | IDENTIFIED_SYMBOL
    | IGNORE_SERVER_IDS_SYMBOL
    | INVOKER_SYMBOL
    | IMPORT_SYMBOL
    | INDEXES_SYMBOL
    | INITIAL_SIZE_SYMBOL
    | INNODB_SYMBOL // Conditionally deprecated in the lexer rule.
    | IO_SYMBOL
    | IPC_SYMBOL
    | ISOLATION_SYMBOL
    | ISSUER_SYMBOL
    | INSERT_METHOD_SYMBOL
    | KEY_BLOCK_SIZE_SYMBOL
    | LAST_SYMBOL
    | LEAVES_SYMBOL
    | LESS_SYMBOL
    | LEVEL_SYMBOL
    | LINESTRING_SYMBOL
    | LIST_SYMBOL
    | LOCAL_SYMBOL
    | LOCKS_SYMBOL
    | LOGFILE_SYMBOL
    | LOGS_SYMBOL
    | MAX_ROWS_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_HEARTBEAT_PERIOD_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_HOST_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_PORT_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_LOG_FILE_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_LOG_POS_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_USER_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_PASSWORD_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SERVER_ID_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_RETRY_COUNT_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_DELAY_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SSL_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SSL_CA_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SSL_CAPATH_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SSL_CERT_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SSL_CIPHER_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SSL_CRL_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SSL_CRLPATH_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_SSL_KEY_SYMBOL
    | MASTER_AUTO_POSITION_SYMBOL
    | MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR_SYMBOL
    | MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR_SYMBOL
    | MAX_STATEMENT_TIME_SYMBOL
    | MAX_SIZE_SYMBOL
    | MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR_SYMBOL
    | MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS_SYMBOL
    | MEDIUM_SYMBOL
    | MEMORY_SYMBOL
    | MERGE_SYMBOL
    | MESSAGE_TEXT_SYMBOL
    | MICROSECOND_SYMBOL
    | MIGRATE_SYMBOL
    | MINUTE_SYMBOL
    | MIN_ROWS_SYMBOL
    | MODIFY_SYMBOL
    | MODE_SYMBOL
    | MONTH_SYMBOL
    | MULTILINESTRING_SYMBOL
    | MULTIPOINT_SYMBOL
    | MULTIPOLYGON_SYMBOL
    | MUTEX_SYMBOL
    | MYSQL_ERRNO_SYMBOL
    | NAME_SYMBOL
    | NAMES_SYMBOL
    | NATIONAL_SYMBOL
    | NCHAR_SYMBOL
    | NDBCLUSTER_SYMBOL
    | NEVER_SYMBOL
    | NEXT_SYMBOL
    | NEW_SYMBOL
    | NO_WAIT_SYMBOL
    | NODEGROUP_SYMBOL
    | NONE_SYMBOL
    | NUMBER_SYMBOL
    | NVARCHAR_SYMBOL
    | OFFSET_SYMBOL
    | OLD_PASSWORD_SYMBOL
    | ONE_SHOT_SYMBOL
    | ONE_SYMBOL
    | PACK_KEYS_SYMBOL
    | PAGE_SYMBOL
    | PARTIAL_SYMBOL
    | PARTITIONING_SYMBOL
    | PARTITIONS_SYMBOL
    | PASSWORD_SYMBOL
    | PHASE_SYMBOL
    | PLUGIN_DIR_SYMBOL
    | PLUGIN_SYMBOL
    | PLUGINS_SYMBOL
    | POINT_SYMBOL
    | POLYGON_SYMBOL
    | PRESERVE_SYMBOL
    | PREV_SYMBOL
    | PRIVILEGES_SYMBOL
    | PROCESS_SYMBOL
    | PROCESSLIST_SYMBOL
    | PROFILE_SYMBOL
    | PROFILES_SYMBOL
    | PROXY_SYMBOL
    | QUARTER_SYMBOL
    | QUERY_SYMBOL
    | QUICK_SYMBOL
    | READ_ONLY_SYMBOL
    | REBUILD_SYMBOL
    | RECOVER_SYMBOL
    | REDO_BUFFER_SIZE_SYMBOL
    | REDOFILE_SYMBOL
    | REDUNDANT_SYMBOL
    | RELAY_SYMBOL
    | RELAYLOG_SYMBOL
    | RELAY_LOG_FILE_SYMBOL
    | RELAY_LOG_POS_SYMBOL
    | RELAY_THREAD_SYMBOL
    | RELOAD_SYMBOL
    | REORGANIZE_SYMBOL
    | REPEATABLE_SYMBOL
    | REPLICATION_SYMBOL
    | REPLICATE_DO_DB_SYMBOL
    | REPLICATE_IGNORE_DB_SYMBOL
    | REPLICATE_DO_TABLE_SYMBOL
    | REPLICATE_IGNORE_TABLE_SYMBOL
    | REPLICATE_WILD_DO_TABLE_SYMBOL
    | REPLICATE_WILD_IGNORE_TABLE_SYMBOL
    | REPLICATE_REWRITE_DB_SYMBOL
    | RESUME_SYMBOL
    | RETURNED_SQLSTATE_SYMBOL
    | RETURNS_SYMBOL
    | REVERSE_SYMBOL
    | ROLLUP_SYMBOL
    | ROUTINE_SYMBOL
    | ROWS_SYMBOL
    | ROW_COUNT_SYMBOL
    | ROW_FORMAT_SYMBOL
    | ROW_SYMBOL
    | RTREE_SYMBOL
    | SCHEDULE_SYMBOL
    | SCHEMA_NAME_SYMBOL
    | SECOND_SYMBOL
    | SERIAL_SYMBOL
    | SERIALIZABLE_SYMBOL
    | SESSION_SYMBOL
    | SIMPLE_SYMBOL
    | SHARE_SYMBOL
    | SHUTDOWN_SYMBOL
    | SLOW_SYMBOL
    | SNAPSHOT_SYMBOL
    | SOUNDS_SYMBOL
    | SOURCE_SYMBOL
    | SQL_AFTER_GTIDS_SYMBOL
    | SQL_AFTER_MTS_GAPS_SYMBOL
    | SQL_BEFORE_GTIDS_SYMBOL
    | SQL_CACHE_SYMBOL
    | SQL_BUFFER_RESULT_SYMBOL
    | SQL_NO_CACHE_SYMBOL
    | SQL_THREAD_SYMBOL
    | STACKED_SYMBOL
    | STARTS_SYMBOL
    | STATS_AUTO_RECALC_SYMBOL
    | STATS_PERSISTENT_SYMBOL
    | STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES_SYMBOL
    | STATUS_SYMBOL
    | STORAGE_SYMBOL
    | STRING_SYMBOL
    | SUBCLASS_ORIGIN_SYMBOL
    | SUBDATE_SYMBOL
    | SUBJECT_SYMBOL
    | SUBPARTITION_SYMBOL
    | SUBPARTITIONS_SYMBOL
    | SUPER_SYMBOL
    | SUSPEND_SYMBOL
    | SWAPS_SYMBOL
    | SWITCHES_SYMBOL
    | TABLE_NAME_SYMBOL
    | TABLES_SYMBOL
    | TABLE_CHECKSUM_SYMBOL
    | TABLESPACE_SYMBOL
    | TEMPORARY_SYMBOL
    | TEMPTABLE_SYMBOL
    | TEXT_SYMBOL
    | THAN_SYMBOL
    | TRANSACTION_SYMBOL
    | TRIGGERS_SYMBOL
    | TIMESTAMP_SYMBOL
    | TIMESTAMP_ADD_SYMBOL
    | TIMESTAMP_DIFF_SYMBOL
    | TIME_SYMBOL
    | TYPES_SYMBOL
    | TYPE_SYMBOL
    | UDF_RETURNS_SYMBOL
    | FUNCTION_SYMBOL
    | UNCOMMITTED_SYMBOL
    | UNDEFINED_SYMBOL
    | UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE_SYMBOL
    | UNDOFILE_SYMBOL
    | UNKNOWN_SYMBOL
    | UNTIL_SYMBOL
    | USER_RESOURCES_SYMBOL
    | USER_SYMBOL
    | USE_FRM_SYMBOL
    | VARIABLES_SYMBOL
    | VIEW_SYMBOL
    | VALUE_SYMBOL
    | WARNINGS_SYMBOL
    | WAIT_SYMBOL
    | WEEK_SYMBOL
    | WORK_SYMBOL
    | WEIGHT_STRING_SYMBOL
    | X509_SYMBOL
    | XID_SYMBOL
    | XML_SYMBOL
    | YEAR_SYMBOL
    ;
finally
{
    retval.start->setType(retval.start, IDENTIFIER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entire `finally` block. It was a hack to set the return type of the terminal of the start token this rule returns to `IDENTIFIER`. However, that type is actually never checked. Only the fact this rule matches is important.

Comment: How much for you to convert your MySQL grammar to ANTLR4?